# How to pass all field values from one view to another by a single object?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I have two views **1.UserInfo** **2.EditUserInfo**

In view **UserInfo** there are lots of filed on the view

I want to pass that values to **EditUserInfo** view using a single object

Is there any in build option in Ext JS to pass all field values from one view to another using single view-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your fields are in a `formpanel` (they better be), the easiest would be to use [`formpanel.getValues()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.Panel.html#method-getValues) and [`formpanel.getForm().setValues()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-setValues).